# Prism 5: How to make a Wizard in a popup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, wizard

We have started a WPF application using the PRISM framework(V5).

One of our desired behavior is to display a modal popup, in which we can find a wizard with several steps.

I'm wondering what is the best way of doing it? Do I have to create an new shell with some navigation inside? What do you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried reading the Prism documentation? There is a ton of guidance.

Comment: In that situation, I simply create another region, and place all the navigations for the wizzard inside that region. On top of it, you could add some shadow or tint etc effect to make your view look like it was a popup.

Comment: There are many solutions for doing this (including Prism), they all come with pros and cons. I also wrote [a very lengthy article about it here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) which would easily support the functionality you describe.

Comment: I've found an extensive documentation on how to do it within the initial shell, but I've some trouble to see how I should display a new popup, with multiple pages